# Motherboard backplates/IO shields: standard unique id code or configurator to help buy correct one?

Tags: motherboard

Is there a standard unique id code to identify the motherboard backplate or a online configurator to help with buying the correct backplate with the port holes punched out?

I've tried searching ebay for the one for my motherboard but the results throw up motherboards themselves too - which I don't need.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The backplates usually only come with the motherboard.

Comment: What motherboard do you have ? Asus have some backplates on their estore

Comment: @Lawrence ASRock G31M-GS - 2.0 - motherboard - micro ATX - LGA775 Socket - G31 - just bought it off ebay not sure if it will come with its usual backplate, have contacted the seller...

Comment: Will this one fit ? - http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-IO-I-O-plate-SHIELD-for-ASROCK-N68-S-UCC-G31M-GS-R2-0-G31DE-A785GM-NO-10-/281159321698

Comment: +1 Lawrence yeah I think so, shame it has the punched out hole for the parallel port - which this board doesn't have. Any suggestions as to how to fill this in welcome. Thanks.

Comment: sticky tape ? or Duct tape ?